# VHDL allow to pass real (floating point) numbers through ports?

Tags: vhdl, quartus

VHDL allow to pass real (floating point) numbers through ports?

For this code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
use IEEE.math_real.all;

entity FPP_MULT is
  port(A        : in  integer;  --input operands
       B        : in  real
       );
end FPP_MULT;

architecture (...)
```

Output:

`Error (10414): VHDL Unsupported Feature error at real.vhd(8): cannot synthesize non-constant real objects or values
Error: Quartus II Create Symbol File was unsuccessful. 1 error, 0 warnings`

Comment: Read the error message. It is not about the port. Quartus (and every other synthesis tool I know) can **not synthesize** reals/float numbers.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008  5.2.5 Floating-point types "An implementation shall choose a representation for all floating-point types except for universal_real that conforms either to IEEE Std 754-1985 or to IEEE Std 854-1987; in either case, a minimum representation size of 64 bits is required for this chosen representation." Type real is host implementation dependent. Also see Annex D Potentially nonportable constructs. Instead consider using a synthesis eligible instantiated package float_pkg type float where the *binary* format can be portably specified.

Comment: See [VHDL-2008 Support Library](https://github.com/FPHDL/fphdl) on github. There's a -1993 compatibility version that's successfully been used with Quartus II.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any type in a port declaration including `real`. But ...

VHDL is a simulation and documentation language for digital circuit behavior. Some clever folks found out, that a subset of the language can be synthesized. Type `real` is not in the synthesizable subset. Even if it could be synthesized by one tool, it would not behave the same way in other tools. It would be a non-portable item.